# Having an image appear multiple times Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a single battery image appearing once here and it moves from right to left then goes away. I want batteries constantly coming and going until the player hits one of them. 
My question is how do I get the batteries to keep on coming until a player hits it? I want them to appear maybe 100 units apart.

```
from pygame import * 
import os
import random
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d, %d" %(0, 0)
init()
#set screen size
size = width, height = 800, 600
screen = display.set_mode(size)
#set fonts
fontGame=font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 30)
fontBack=font.SysFont("Ariel", 30)
fontTitle=font.SysFont("Ariel", 100)
fontResearch=font.SysFont ("Times New Roman", 18)
#set button and page to 0
button = 0
page=0

#setting colours
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (106,186,232)
#loading image
backgroundPic=image.load("Background.jpg")
backgroundGame=image.load("gameBackground.jpg")
backgroundGame=transform.scale(backgroundGame,(800,600))
battery=image.load("Battery.png")
battery=transform.scale(battery,(100,100))

backgroundx=0
playerPic=image.load("player.png")
playerPic=transform.scale(playerPic,(70,70))

batteryx=[]


#defining what is going to be shown on the screen
def drawScene(screen, button,page,locationx,locationy): 
    global batteryx
    mx, my = mouse.get_pos() #will get where the mouse is
    #if the user does nothing
    if page==0:
        draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0,0, width, height))

        screen.fill(BLACK)
        rel_backgroundx= backgroundx % backgroundGame.get_rect().width
        screen.blit(backgroundGame, (rel_backgroundx - backgroundGame.get_rect().width,0))
        if rel_backgroundx < width:
            screen.blit (backgroundGame, (rel_backgroundx,0))
        screen.blit(playerPic,(locationx,locationy))

        screen.blit(battery,(batteryx,420))                
        batteryx-=1               

    display.flip()
    return page

#def collision (battery, playerPic):
    #if battery.colliderect(playerPic):
        #return True
    #return False

running = True
myClock = time.Clock()

KEY_LEFT= False
KEY_RIGHT= False
KEY_UP= False
KEY_DOWN= False
locationx=0
jumping=False
accel=20
onGround= height-150
locationy=onGround

batteryx=random.randrange(50,width,10)  

# Game Loop
while running:
    button=0
    print (KEY_LEFT, KEY_RIGHT)
    for evnt in event.get():             # checks all events that happen
        if evnt.type == QUIT:
            running=False
        if evnt.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mx,my=evnt.pos
            button = evnt.button
        if evnt.type== KEYDOWN:
            if evnt.key==K_LEFT:
                KEY_LEFT= True
                KEY_RIGHT= False
            if evnt.key==K_RIGHT:
                KEY_RIGHT= True
                KEY_LEFT= False
            if evnt.key==K_UP and jumping==False:
                jumping=True 
                accel=20
            if evnt.key== K_DOWN:
                KEY_DOWN= True
                KEY_UP= False 
        if evnt.type==KEYUP:
            if evnt.key==K_LEFT:
                KEY_LEFT= False
            if evnt.key==K_RIGHT:
                KEY_RIGHT= False
            if evnt.key==K_DOWN:
                KEY_DOWN=False

    if KEY_LEFT== True:
        locationx-=10
        backgroundx+=10
    if KEY_RIGHT== True:
        locationx+=10
        backgroundx-=10
    if jumping==True:
        locationy-=accel
        accel-=1
        if locationy>=onGround:
            jumping=False
            locationy=onGround

    #player cannot move off screen
    if locationx<0:
        locationx=0
    if locationx>400:
        locationx=400
    #if collision(battery, playerPic)==True:
        #screen.fill(BLACK)

    page=drawScene(screen,button,page,locationx,locationy)
    myClock.tick(60)  # waits long enough to have 60 fps
    if page==6:  #if last button is clicked program closes
        running=False

quit()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Create a list of rects which serve as the positions of the batteries. Use `for` loops to update the rects and blit the battery image at the rects. Remove rects that have left the screen and append new rects to create new batteries.

Comment: could you post an example please @skrx

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of rects which serve as the positions of the batteries. Use for loops to update the rects and blit the battery image at the rects. Remove rects that have left the screen and append new rects to create new batteries

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')

battery_image = pg.Surface((30, 50))
battery_image.fill(pg.Color('sienna1'))

# Append pygame.Rect objects to this list.
batteries = []
batteries.append(battery_image.get_rect(topleft=(700, 100)))
battery_speed = -5
battery_timer = 40

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True

    # A simple frame based timer.
    battery_timer -= 1
    if battery_timer <= 0:
        battery_timer = 40
        # After 40 frames a new rect gets appended to the list.
        batteries.append(battery_image.get_rect(topleft=(700, 100)))

    temp_list = []
    # Iterate over the rects to update them.
    for battery_rect in batteries:
        battery_rect.x += battery_speed
        # Rects with x <= 50 won't be appended to the temp_list.
        if battery_rect.x > 50:
            temp_list.append(battery_rect)

    # Assign the list with the remaining rects to the batteries variable.
    batteries = temp_list

    # Blit everything.
    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    for battery_rect in batteries:
        screen.blit(battery_image, battery_rect)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
```